# How can I set the limit of redisearch? The default limit is 10. I want to set it to 50

Tags: python, django, redis, redisearch

Consider:

```
from redisearch import Client

client = Client('myIndex')
res = client.search(search_key)
```

How can I get 50 results for `res`?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the [paging](http://redisearch.io/python_client/#paging) method of the *Query* object.

Comment: The link is dead, and there's no info on `paging` even on the client docs (https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/). No info either on how to tweak LIMIT.

Comment: This was the repo: https://github.com/RediSearch/redisearch-py, which is now deprecated.

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken (it redirects and there isn't anything about paging or a "paging" method on that page).

Answer (score 2):

Add paging:

```
index.search(Query("@phrase:asd").paging(0, 1000))
```

So you will have a maximum of 1000 results.